# PHP or C# or (X)? HTTP Request every 10 seconds and Chart image generation

Tags: c#, php, ruby, image-processing, charts

**Objective: HTTP Request every 10 seconds, chart image generation on server and upload back to user's browser for display**

I wanted to go with LAMP + pChart but worried it might not handle > 1000 of simultaneous users and slow the server down to a crawl.

I thought about offloading the chart image generation to Google Charts but if the request is once every 10 seconds, I'd blast through the daily limit easily.

What server + lang is best for this implementation? Would I need to think about scaling at this point yet?

Comment: The correct server + lang is the one that you build it on.  All the languages are capable.  They all have pluses and minuses.  There is no golden ticket.  What you are asking is a very subjective question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A low end dedicated server, or a mid-range VPS will handle this no matter what language and platform you choose. 1000 simultaneous users requesting a chart every 10 seconds is an average of only 100 requests per second. I generate over 1000 dynamic images per second on a standard LAMP/PHP stack and it doesn't really generate much load at all.

Answer (score 0):

While it will depend on the charting library, honestly one request every 10 seconds is not that much. You won't go wrong with any of the languages and either LAMP or IIS.

Comment: One thousand clients, each requesting their own chart every ten seconds, averages out to 100 charts per second -- if that is a new process execution for each one, it'll feel like a lot. If it is all done in one process, it will probably be able to keep up. It feels like enough to think about at least. :)